# Is it better to use parameter or column value when copying data from one table to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, insert

I have a SQL statement to copy records from one table to another:

```
INSERT INTO [deletedItems] (
    [id],
    [shopId])
SELECT 
    [id],
    [shopId]
FROM [items]
WHERE shopId = @ShopId
```

@ShopId is a parameter provided to the sql command when calling the db from my application code.

Will it make the statement perform better if I change it to use the provided parameter directly, so the SQL server does not have to include `shopId` column from products table in the projection?

```
INSERT INTO [deletedItems](
    [id],
    [shopId])
SELECT 
    [id],
    @ShopId
FROM [items]
WHERE shopId = @ShopId
```

Intuition is telling me yes, but at the same time, I would expect the sql server to optimize the execution plan of the first query and ommit the projection of the `shopId` column anyways (because the value will be the same for all the records) and use a constant value instead.

Comment: We don't use intuition to know which is "better". And we need to define what "better" means and how you intend to measure it. For performance questions, the answer is always the same. You do it both ways and compare the execution plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would expect the sql server to optimize the execution plan of the
>   first query and ommit the projection of the shopId column anyways
>   (because the value will be the same for all the records) and use a
>   constant value instead.

No, SQL Server, does not do this. You can verify this by looking at the execution plan and the "output columns" for the operator accessing `items`.

In the general case this is not a safe transformation and can lead to lost information. For example if the source matches the rows

```
+--------+
| ShopId |
+--------+
| A123   |
| a123   |
+--------+
```

Then on a case insensitive collation both would match the same predicate and should be inserted but are different.

If one of the following applies

- You are using a datatype where this is not possible
- You know that this is not an issue in your data - e.g. as check constraints ensure all data is stored trimmed and upper case.
- Are happy for a canonical representation to be used for all rows if it is an issue.

then it is possible to come up with convoluted scenarios where your manual optimisation makes sense as below

```
CREATE TABLE #T(X INT IDENTITY, Y CHAR(4000));

INSERT INTO #T
SELECT TOP 1000000 REPLICATE('A',4000)
FROM sys.all_objects o1, sys.all_objects o2

SELECT X, Y
FROM #T
WHERE Y = REPLICATE('A',4000)
ORDER BY X


SELECT X, REPLICATE('A',4000) AS Y
FROM #T
WHERE Y = REPLICATE('A',4000)
ORDER BY X
```

The size of the rows going into the sort operator is much bigger in the first case as it includes the large string column and the sort spills to `tempdb`. The query execution takes substantially longer as a result. The memory grant request for the second query is the same as that of the first as it does not take into account that the column is computed after the sort but there is less data to sort and it does not spill. On versions of SQL Server where adaptive memory grant feedback is available the excessive grant would be corrected if the query is executed repeatedly.

In most real world scenarios I doubt the manual optimisation will make any practical difference however so you should choose whichever one does what you need and you feel is clearer and concentrate optimisation efforts in more promising areas (for me the second one makes clearer that the same value will be inserted in all rows).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't except any performances differences. The slow part will be finding the correct items by `@ShopID` or the IO operations.

What can improve your query performance is having an index on `[ShopID]` column where `ID` is primary key or included column.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it makes the statement perform better if I change it to use the
>   provided parameter directly

It's the same. Because your result just has a unique `ShopId` as `Where` clause.

```
INSERT INTO [deletedItems] (
    [id],
    [shopId])
SELECT 
    [id],
    [shopId]
FROM [items]
WHERE shopId = @ShopId -- this condition makes the `shopId` value is become unique
```

Answer (score 0):

Two important points.

The calculation of scalar expressions in the `SELECT` (generally) has little impact on query performance.  The performance is determined by data movement.

So, selecting a "constant" versus selecting a column from a table is immaterial.

Second, if you care about performance, you need to be very careful about query plans.  Either force the use of an index or be sure that the query gets recompiled periodically as the data changes in your tables.

In particular, you want to be sure that the query uses an index on `items(shopId)` if the table spans multiple data pages.